# Fixed values not accepted in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

[image: Query]

I created the above query for a time range, and I am attempting to add it to the parameters
[image: Adding to Parameters]

Although this is a fixed value, I am unable to get the query to accept the fixed value.

Is there any other way to approach this?

Comment: What is your expression for the specified value?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are approaching this incorrectly. As far as I know you cannot use the results of a query to populate a parameter value like that.

If the below does not work, then I would edit your question, show a sample of the data you are working with, the parameter labels you want to show and then the expected outcome.

At the moment your parameter value will just be a text string that looks like a t-sql query

You probably just need to edit your dataset query and parameter values.

For example. Set you parameters values to

| Label | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Shift 1 | 1 |
| Shift 2 | 2 |
| Shift 3 | 3 |

Then your dataset query would look something like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE CAST(myDateTimeColumn AS Time) BETWEEN
        CASE @Shift 
            WHEN 1 THEN CAST('21:00:00' AS Time)
            WHEN 2 THEN CAST('22:00:00' AS Time)
            WHEN 3 THEN CAST('23:00:00' AS Time)
        END
    AND 
        CASE @Shift 
            WHEN 1 THEN CAST('21:59:59' AS Time)
            WHEN 2 THEN CAST('22:59:59' AS Time)
            WHEN 3 THEN CAST('23:59:59' AS Time)
        END
```

This won't be perfect as it would miss anything less than a second before a new hour but should get you on the right track.

note: This is also untested as it's done from memory